# Using a for loop to set a value without replacing existing value when using the same class

Tags: java, xml, for-loop

I need help on how to setting the value using for loop without replace the existing value when using the class. For example , i need to print out three different value which are test1,test2,test3. Below was the code,

```
    PaymentInstructionInformation3 paymentInstructionInformation3 =  new PaymentInstructionInformation3();
    for(int i=0 ;i<4;i++){
        if(i==1)
        {
            PartyIdentification32 partyIdentification32Body1 = new PartyIdentification32();
            partyIdentification32Body1.setNm("test1");
            paymentInstructionInformation3.setDbtr(partyIdentification32Body1);

        }else
        if(i==2)
        {
            PartyIdentification32 partyIdentification32Body2 = new PartyIdentification32();
            partyIdentification32Body2.setNm("test2");
            paymentInstructionInformation3.setDbtr(partyIdentification32Body2);

        }else
        if(i==3)
        {
            PartyIdentification32 partyIdentification32Body3 = new PartyIdentification32();
            partyIdentification32Body3.setNm("test3");
            paymentInstructionInformation3.setDbtr(partyIdentification32Body3);
        }
    }
    totalLst.add(paymentInstructionInformation3);
```

Current Output

```
 <PmtInf>
        <Dbtr>
            <Nm>test3</Nm>
        </Dbtr>
 </PmtInf>
```

Expected Output

```
 <PmtInf>
        <Dbtr>
            <Nm>test1</Nm>
            <Nm>test2</Nm>
            <Nm>test3</Nm>
        </Dbtr>
 </PmtInf>
```

Implement class

```
        protected String nm; 
       public String getNm() {
        return nm;
        }
      public void setNm(String value) {
        this.nm = value;
        }
```

Thank You for Helping

Comment: remove if conditions.

Comment: Please put setNm() implementation code

Comment: The reason to use if else statement is because of the position.The value must exactly same as the position inside the list.For example(test1,,test3) ,

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this line:

```
totalLst.add(paymentInstructionInformation3);
```

into for loop. This causes `totalList` have 3 `paymentInstructionInformation3` added inside for loop.

If doesn't help please write what happens

Comment: it will print <PmtInf> and  <Dbtr> three time too, what i expected is only<Nm> need to print out three time.Btw, thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need if statements? You are doing the exact same thing in each block

Also, you must add to the list inside the loop, not after its over

```
for(int i=1 ;i<4;i++){
    PaymentInstructionInformation3 pay =  new PaymentInstructionInformation3();

    PartyIdentification32 party = new PartyIdentification32();
    party.setNm("test"+i);
    pay.setDbtr(party);

    totalLst.add(pay) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please place paymentInstructionInformation3 object creation statement inside the for loop as first statement. This will avoid overriding the values. place totalLst.add() statements inside the for loop as the last statement so that all three items will be added to the list.

Answer (score 0):

This line TotalLst.add(paymentInstructionInformation3); is out of the loop. So, it just do add only once rather than third times.

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things:
1. You can put initializing and instantiation of
paymentInstructionInformation3
into loop before if/else block and row
totalLst.add(paymentInstructionInformation3);
after this block. But in this case you will have 3 instances of PaymentInstructionInformation3.
2. You can keep member of class PaymentInstructionInformation3 which called I guess nm not as single entity but as a list of this entities. And in every  if/else parts you can add value to this list.

Comment: what you saying exactly what i need,nm is a list of entities, so how can i keep the member of class when each time of loop?

Comment: @HolicGoh I mean do smth like this
`code`
class PartyIdentification32
{

  // you can keep nm in such manner
  List<String> nm = new ArrayList<>();

  // so you need to refactor this method
  public void setNm(String nmValue)
  {
    nm.add(nmValue);
  }
}
`code`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, why are you using a loop to create the *partyIdentification*? Since you always create a partyIdentification32BodyN, you could just instantiate them without the loop. It would stay like this:

```
PaymentInstructionInformation3 paymentInstructionInformation3 =  new PaymentInstructionInformation3();

PartyIdentification32 partyIdentification32Body1 = new PartyIdentification32();
partyIdentification32Body1.setNm("test1");
paymentInstructionInformation3.setDbtr(partyIdentification32Body1);

PartyIdentification32 partyIdentification32Body2 = new PartyIdentification32();
partyIdentification32Body2.setNm("test2");
paymentInstructionInformation3.setDbtr(partyIdentification32Body2);

PartyIdentification32 partyIdentification32Body3 = new PartyIdentification32();
partyIdentification32Body3.setNm("test3");
paymentInstructionInformation3.setDbtr(partyIdentification32Body3);
```

Secondly, it looks like your *paymentInstructionInformation3.setDbtr* does not add the *partyIdentification32BodyN* to a List, replacing the former value.

You could change the *paymentInstructionInformation3.setDbtr* to *paymentInstructionInformation3.addDbtr* and add the parameter to a List inside PaymentInstructionInformation3. Example:

```
class PaymentInstructionInformation3 {
    List<PartyIdentification32> dbtrList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addDbtr(PartyIdentification32 debtr) {
        this.dbtrList.add(debtr);
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.